# Is using @Injectable providedIn for any non-lazy-loaded module the same as providedIn: "root"?

Tags: angular, angular-di

I've read the docs thoroughly and, although I can't find exactly where it's referenced, I have the impression that declaring a service in an eagerly loaded module's `providers` array will make the singleton available to the application scope. If this is true,

> Is using `@Injectable` `providedIn` for any non-lazy-loaded module the same as `providedIn: "root"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is the same.

In general, you should always just use the providedIn: "root" syntax in the @Injectable declaration. It even works with lazy loading when its just loaded in one module, so the service wont be loaded until angular loads the module. Its a way better construct.

I think the only 2 exceptions to prefering providedIn are
1) You want to declare it in a component. This will cause it to not be a singleton, but scoped to the component
2) You are using it in 2 separate, but both lazy loaded modules (and its also not used in the initial load), in this case I believe the best choices is eagerly load it by bringing it into the AppModule on initial load.

Comment: sadly there is this reason to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25784#issuecomment-532055631

This doesn't always allow the developer to use injectable instead of providers